# Wpf control connect strings in Text/Content

Tags: c#, wpf

I have Button with Resources:

```
Content="{x:Static resPath:Resources.ZoomIn}"
```

which value = "Zoom in". I want to add to this content " x1". To get value = "Zoom in x1".

I want do something like this:

```
Content="{x:Static resPath:Resources.ZoomIn} + x1"
Content="{x:Static resPath:Resources.ZoomIn} + {x1}"
```

But it throw error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a TextBlock as Content:

```
<Button>
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="{x:Static resPath:Resources.ZoomIn}"/>
        <Run Text="x1"/>
    </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

or

```
<Button>
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="{x:Static resPath:Resources.ZoomIn}"/> x1
    </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

Comment: I think this is a cleaner way to achieve the result. We don't know the full requirement but I guess you could well be "zooming in" different amounts such as x1 or x2 or x3. Using a slider value even.  Separate runs ( perhaps 3  with the x in another ) would allow you to bind that number.

Comment: @Andy I think that is a personal preference, but I agree that the markup syntax is more complex and harder to read, I added it as alternative approach to what @Clemens suggested. I just want to add, that for the scenario that you describe, you could as well use `StringFormat` in a `MultiBinding`.

Comment: One thing is for sure. You don't actually *need* a Binding to achieve the desired result. IMO it just adds unnecessary complexity and should therefore be avoided.

Comment: I would say it's an engineering principle to choose the simplest option. Easier to read and simpler are deciding factors.  But an app is still going to work fine using either approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `TextBlock` with a `Binding` and [`StringFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat?view=netcore-3.1) to format the bound text.

```
<Button>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static resPath:Resources.ZoomIn}, StringFormat={}{0} x1}"/>
</Button>
```

The `{}` is an [escape sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/escape-sequence-markup-extension?redirectedfrom=MSDN), `{0}` just refers to the bound value (when binding multiple values with e.g. a `MultiBinding` you could access more than one) and the rest is the your custom text.

Comment: This would make sense in case ZoomIn is a static property with change notification. You would write `Text="{Binding Path=(resPath:Resources.ZoomIn), StringFormat={}{0} x1}"`.

Comment: Sorry, but in this way it turned out that it does not correctly display the button positions in the stack panel.